# Ubuntu 12.04 on Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: 12.04, samsung, smartphone, ubuntu-for-android

I have Samsung Galaxy Pocket (full model name: Samsung Galaxy gt-s5300)

Is there way to install Ubuntu  properly on this device? If so, how to do so?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so that's an good idea of doing it. U need to wait untill the Ubuntu becomes available for the tablets. Still there more than the rough edges not applicable in the ubuntu to be working on the Tablet. I installed it in Nexus 7 .. I am not satisfied with it. But i hope canonical along with mark can pull it back.. But my only worry is they need to pull back as soon as possible..

Kindly do it before this may (That means they should be ready with the ubuntu 13.04)